# Pass URL Parameter Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring, url, spring-webflow

I have this web application using Spring Web Flow framework. In my main page I have a default display of a list of employees. When I click a particular row I need to redirect to another page displaying a detailed view of the row. I was thinking of passing the "name" field in my row through URL parameter.

Is this possible or can Spring web flow support getting parameters from the URL?

```
<a href="edit.do?row_name=testName">name</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your request parameters from the special EL variable `requestParameters`.  See: http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#el-variable-requestParameters

Comment: I did something like in the on-entry :
<evaluate expression="myBean.myMethod(requestParameters.row_name)" result="flowScope.myvariable"/>